# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory while running play project in intellij idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jboss, playframework

I am trying to create a play framework project in intellij idea .But when i am trying to run or debug my project it shows the below error in my console.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory
        at play.api.test.TestServer.start(Selenium.scala:142)
        at play.api.test.PlayRunners$class.running(Helpers.scala:59)
        at play.api.test.Helpers$.running(Helpers.scala:364)
        at play.api.test.WithBrowser.around(Specs.scala:57)
        at org.specs2.mutable.Around$class.delayedInit(Around.scala:12)
        at play.api.test.WithBrowser.delayedInit(Specs.scala:45)
        at IntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon$1.<init>(IntegrationSpec.scala:17)
        at IntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IntegrationSpec.scala:17)
        at IntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IntegrationSpec.scala:17)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentsBuilder$$anon$1.asResult(FragmentsBuilder.scala:142)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentsBuilder$$anon$1.asResult(FragmentsBuilder.scala:141)
        at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(Result.scala:250)
        at org.specs2.specification.Example$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Fragment.scala:209)
        at org.specs2.specification.Example$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Fragment.scala:209)
        at org.specs2.specification.Example.execute(Fragment.scala:176)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$$anonfun$1.apply(FragmentExecution.scala:52)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$$anonfun$1.apply(FragmentExecution.scala:52)
        at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
        at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:116)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$class.executeBody(FragmentExecution.scala:28)
        at org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner$$anon$3.executeBody(JUnitRunner.scala:43)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$class.execute(FragmentExecution.scala:52)
        at org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner$$anon$3.execute(JUnitRunner.scala:43)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$$anonfun$executeFragment$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FragmentExecution.scala:35)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$$anonfun$executeFragment$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(FragmentExecution.scala:35)
        at org.specs2.control.Exceptions$class.catchAllOr(Exceptions.scala:54)
        at org.specs2.control.Exceptions$.catchAllOr(Exceptions.scala:109)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(FragmentExecution.scala:35)
        at org.specs2.specification.FragmentExecution$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(FragmentExecution.scala:35)
        at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitReporter$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.execute$1(JUnitReporter.scala:47)
        at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitReporter$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(JUnitReporter.scala:54)
        at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitReporter$$anonfun$executeFragment$1.apply(JUnitReporter.scala:46)
        at org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$class.executeWithBarrier$1(ExecutionStrategy.scala:103)
        at org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$$anonfun$executeConcurrently$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionStrategy.scala:105)
        at org.specs2.reporter.DefaultExecutionStrategy$$anonfun$executeConcurrently$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionStrategy.scala:105)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Promise$Unfulfilled$.fulfill(Promise.scala:125)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Promise$Done.eval(Promise.scala:153)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Promise$$anonfun$e$1.apply(Promise.scala:17)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Promise$$anonfun$e$1.apply(Promise.scala:17)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Actor.batchHandle(Actor.scala:73)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Actor.scalaz$concurrent$Actor$$act(Actor.scala:57)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Actor$$anonfun$schedule$1.apply$mcV$sp(Actor.scala:52)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Actor$$anonfun$schedule$1.apply(Actor.scala:52)
        at scalaz.concurrent.Actor$$anonfun$schedule$1.apply(Actor.scala:52)
        at scalaz.concurrent.StrategysLow$$anon$3$$anon$4.call(Strategy.scala:65)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 50 more

    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory
        at play.api.test.TestServer.start(Selenium.scala:146)
        at play.api.test.PlayRunners$class.running(Helpers.scala:59)
        at play.api.test.Helpers$.running(Helpers.scala:364)
        at play.api.test.WithBrowser.around(Specs.scala:57)
        at play.api.test.WithBrowser.delayedInit(Specs.scala:45)
        at IntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon$1.<init>(IntegrationSpec.scala:17)
        at IntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IntegrationSpec.scala:17)
        at IntegrationSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IntegrationSpec.scala:17)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory
        at play.api.test.TestServer.start(Selenium.scala:142)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        ... 8 more

    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:1698', transport: 'socket'

    Process finished with exit code -1
```

I have play plugins installed in intellij and created my project from File -> New Project -> scala ->Play2.x

Why my play project is  not able to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all , check that your class name and file name is same, if it is true.
Then , check that your class path is specified properly and after the declaration of the class path you have not edited the folders name which are there in the class path or have changed there location .